# Getting No such file or directory when hitting curl command from sh file in gitLab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Below is the curl command that I am running from one of the sh file, getting d_response.json: No such file or directory

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -o d_response.json -w "%{http_code}" -k -s --header "X-Api-Key: $API_KEY" --request GET $API_URL/api/v1/project?name=$CI_PROJECT_NAME
```

Does it something related to jq?
I have verified api key and api url mentioned is correct in the command.